# MIPS I/O Trouble

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm currently working on a program in MIPS that generates PseudoRandom numbers using the Linear Congruence method. The program is supposed to take in several values that will be used in the generation of these numbers, but I've run into a problem: every time I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

```
 Unknown System call: (whatever number was entered in)
```

The troublesome code is as follows:

```
# first, get the seed for the base case
  la            $a0,  SeedPrompt
  li            $v0,  4
  syscall

  # print a new line
  la            $a0,  NewLine
  li            $v0,  4
  syscall

  # read integer
  li            $v0,  5
  syscall

  sw            $v0, Seed   (Seed is declared earlier in the file as a word)
  syscall
```

I've been using several guides (including one provided by my professor) to help me program this segment, and it looks correct when compared to those. I feel like I should also mention that this is my first time programming anything in assembly, so I'm still not used to the syntax of the language. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is there a `syscall` after `sw`? That makes no sense.

Comment: Yes that `syscall` is suspicious. If i understand correct so are allocating memory dynamically in heaps. if you post your other part of code it will be easier to debug.